# When did EU governments sell their energy industries and grid to the private sector?

Tags: energy-policy, energy-independence

Yanis Varoufakis [says that](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NicE0-N9ux0&t=156s) complex, secretive and disfavorable market "auction" laws have slowly evolved in the EU to the detriment of consumers and the benefit of energy companies.

The laws are used to sell the lowest cost energy for the same price as the highest energy commodity.

When did EU governments lose control over the supply law and price of the electricity on their utility grids, by what mechanism, to what degree?

Comment: First we should establish what exactly has been lost. Did Vanis Varoufakis maybe add some details about what exactly may have happened there? It's not clear. Energy production and consumption is not a trivial undertaking. Basically consumers expect to be delivered with arbitrary amounts of energy at any time they desire so. That cannot really be cheap.

Comment: He is talking about the high price despite autonomy, so the UK production cost has dropped massively from 50% wind generation... UK is nearly 100% independant for electric, but the prices are unstable and profits are rising against inflation, while The best way to see the result of the policies are the graphs adjusted for inflation. For all of the EU, the price seems to have risen by to 20% despite technology lowering overal electricity cost, and houses become more energy-efficient, the bills rise anyway. https://www.google.com/search?q=price+of+energy+per+kwh+since+graph+EU&tbm=isch

Comment: I thought that despite better energy efficiency the demand for electric energy is still continuing to rise in Europe. And some projects get more and more expensive like the nuclear power station in Hinkley Point in the UK which is under construction. Someone has to pay for it.